# Synonym graph token filter giving incorrect results with synonyms - ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, synonym

***Configuration file:***

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 0,
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "synonym": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "graph_synonyms",
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "graph_synonyms": {
                    "type": "synonym_graph",
                    "synonyms_path": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/synonym.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "synonym"
            },
            "seniority": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Synonyms File:** synonmys.txt

```
Human Resources, HR

Vice President, VP
```

Match Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "Resources"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result List** of `title` for above query

1. `HR Chief`
2. `Vice President, Human Resources`
3. `HR Officer, North America`

Here Result #2 is expected but #1 and #3 are **unexpected** because I am searching with only  `Resources` and #1 and #3 doesn't contain that word and we haven't defined synonym for `Resources`.

Please help me with this issue and let me know where I am going wrong.

**ElasticSearch Installation details:**

```
{
  "name" : "elasticsearch01",
  "cluster_name" : "test-01",
  "cluster_uuid" : "K5u4d_pdQx2KDYWiiksCwQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "1c34507e66d7db1211f66f3513706fdf548736aa",
    "build_date" : "2020-12-05T01:00:33.671820Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: it seems matching because of "tokenizer": "whitespace". Not sure what else we can try !

Comment: @DaxJoshi
I have tried using  ```"tokenizer": "standard"```. But still this issue persist.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because of how you defined the filter. Based on the [Elasticsearch Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html#_solr_synonyms):

```
# Equivalent synonyms may be separated with commas and give
# no explicit mapping.  In this case, the mapping behavior will
# be taken from the expand parameter in the schema.  This allows
# the same synonym file to be used in different synonym handling strategies.
# Examples:
ipod, i-pod, i pod
foozball , foosball
universe , cosmos
lol, laughing out loud

# If expand==true, "ipod, i-pod, i pod" is equivalent
# to the explicit mapping:
ipod, i-pod, i pod => ipod, i-pod, i pod
# If expand==false, "ipod, i-pod, i pod" is equivalent
# to the explicit mapping:
ipod, i-pod, i pod => iPod
```

In your case, the `Human Resources, HR` translates to `Human Resources, HR => Human Resources, HR` since *expand* is true by default. The following tokens are produced for each of the titles when index.

```
HR Chief -> human, resources, hr, chief
Vice President, Human Resources -> vice, president, hr, human, resources
HR Officer, North America -> hr, human, resources, officer, north, america
```

Thus when you search for `Resources`, all the documents are a match.

If you want to run your searches without matching the added synonyms, you can create a [multi field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) and run your search against the other `title.raw` field.

```
... 
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "synonym"
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            },
```

BTW, you can easily check the tokens produced for a field by Elasticsearch using the [*_analyze*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) API. For instance

```
curl "localhost:9200/<YOUR_INDEX>/_analyze?pretty" -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"field": "title", "text": "HR Officer, North America" }
```